# Hot to start runnable .jar on mac by double clicking?

Tags: eclipse, macos, executable-jar, java-12

I would like to start my java code by double-click.Therefore I have exported my java project in Eclipse as "Runnable .jar". The file has the java icon, but when I try to start it, an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJmv1.png) appears:

> "The Java JAR file "test.jar" could not be launched. Check the Console
>   for possible error messages."

But there is nothing in the console. 
I am running OSX 10.14.5, Java 12 in Eclipse as JDR, and on my Mac there is Java 8 installed. 
Running `java -jar /Users/Bob/Desktop/test.jar` does start the program.

```
package testMAC;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }

}
```

The program should start the console and print "It works!".

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/how-do-i-run-a-jar-when-i-double-click-it

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/how-do-i-work-with-development-build-on-macos-netbeans-11-0/ and here http://www.owsiak.org/netbeans-make-macos-installer-beautiful-again/ to get an idea how to prepare nice looking wrapper for Java based code.

Comment: But why do some .jar files work just fine?